# Countdown timer every 3 days

Tags: javascript

I'm a little confused. I need to get the 1st day of the month should start counting for 3 days. By the time the expiration restarted.

```js
var today = new Date(),
    end = new Date( today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth(), today.getDate() + 3 );

var timer = setInterval(function() {
  var differenceTime, dd, hh, mm, ss, str;

  if ( ( new Date().getDate() == end.getDate() ) || ( new Date().getDate() == 1 ) ) {
    end = new
  } else {
    differenceTime = end - new Date();

    dd = parseInt(differenceTime / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
    hh = parseInt(differenceTime / (60 * 60 * 1000)) % 24;
    mm = parseInt(differenceTime / (1000 * 60)) % 60;
    ss = parseInt(differenceTime / 1000) % 60;

    document.querySelector('.days').innerHTML = format(dd);
    document.querySelector('.hours').innerHTML = format(hh);
    document.querySelector('.minutes').innerHTML = format(mm);
    document.querySelector('.seconds').innerHTML = format(ss);
  }
}, 1000);

function format(num) {
  return (9 < num) ? num : "0" + num;
};
```

```css
<div class="cowntdown">
  <span class="days"></span>
  <span class="hours"></span>
  <span class="minutes"></span>
  <span class="seconds"></span>
</div>
```

```html
<div class="cowntdown">
  <span class="days"></span>
  <span class="hours"></span>
  <span class="minutes"></span>
  <span class="seconds"></span>
</div>
```

Help make the right condition.

Comment: Your question does not make much sense. Can you clarify what are you trying to achieve? Are you looking for a countdown of 3 days, from the beginning of the month?

Comment: @rpbaltazar, ie 3 days have passed, the timer has to be started again.

Comment: But then the comparison would be made against day 3 or still with day 1? Do you care about which month you are? Or when you change month you start over again from day 1?

Comment: it is necessary that every 3 days and every 1st of the month

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried to reuse as much of your code as possible. If I understood correctly your problem, this should do the trick.
You can probably get some cleaner code if you use [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/), specially when it comes to formatting the text and computing the difference between the dates.

Please keep in mind that the check is not totally exact as it compares the dates up to seconds.

```js
var numberOfDays = 3;
var today = new Date();
var start = getNextStartDate(today);
var end = getNextEndDate(today);

var timer = setInterval(function() {
  var differenceTime, dd, hh, mm, ss, str;
  var now = new Date();
  if (now >= end) {
    start = getNextStartDate(now);
    end = getNextEndDate(now);
  } else {
    differenceTime = end - now;

    dd = parseInt(differenceTime / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
    hh = parseInt(differenceTime / (60 * 60 * 1000)) % 24;
    mm = parseInt(differenceTime / (1000 * 60)) % 60;
    ss = parseInt(differenceTime / 1000) % 60;

    document.querySelector('.days').innerHTML = format(dd);
    document.querySelector('.hours').innerHTML = format(hh);
    document.querySelector('.minutes').innerHTML = format(mm);
    document.querySelector('.seconds').innerHTML = format(ss);
  }
}, 1000);

function getNextEndDate(fromDate) {
  return new Date(fromDate.getFullYear(), fromDate.getMonth(), fromDate.getDate() + numberOfDays);
}

function getNextStartDate(currentDate) {
  var currentDay = currentDate.getDate();
  var index = Math.ceil(currentDay / 3);
  var nextStartDay = 1 + numberOfDays * index
  return new Date(currentDate.getFullYear(), currentDate.getMonth(), nextStartDay);
}

function format(num) {
  return (9 < num) ? num : "0" + num;
};
```

```html
<div class="cowntdown">
  <span class="days"></span>
  <span class="hours"></span>
  <span class="minutes"></span>
  <span class="seconds"></span>
</div>
```

There is also a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rpbaltazar/85jxue8a/6/) if you prefer

Comment: Thank you very match, bro! Nice

Comment: Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.

Comment: Thanks again, bro!